# Missing some components when creating new C# Web Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/E7Voso411Vs?t=545) and I am using VS Community 2017. When I create/select `ASP.NET Web Application` it generates these files and folders:

[image: Image 1]

But according to the tutorial, I should have these:

[image: img2]

Because I'll need stuff like `app_data` for the database.

Please advise.. not sure what to do

Comment: Are you sure you are following the tutorial correctly? The first screenshot looks like an ASP.NET core application whereas the second one looks like a regular .NET Framework ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tutorial is about ASP.NET MVC 5 (.net framework) whether you have created Asp.Net core project.

If you want to learn ASP.NET MVC 5 (.net framework) and follow this tutorial open File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> ASP.NET Web Application (.net framework) and choose MVC Project